# Как обеспечить глобальный межсессионный контекст -- одна переменная на все сессии?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, сессия, контекст

Нужно предотвратить повторный запуск пакетной процедуры. Но не хочу использовать флаг текущего запуска в таблице, хотелось бы брать из памяти. Насколько понял из документации, глобальный контекст доступен только в рамках конкретной сессии.

А как можно обеспечить межсессионное взаимодействие каким-нибудь простым изящным способом?

То есть одна переменная на все сессии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> глобальный контекст доступен только в рамках конкретной сессии

Не совсем так, добавив клаузу `ACCESSED GLOBALLY` контекст станет доступен во всех сессиях.

Вот посмотрите (или попробуйте):

```
create or replace context gctx using gpack accessed globally
/
create or replace package gpack as
    function getnamespace return varchar2;
    procedure setctx (attr varchar2, value varchar2);
    procedure clearctx (attr varchar2); 
end;
/
create or replace package body gpack as
    function getnamespace return varchar2 is begin return 'gctx'; end;
    procedure setctx (attr varchar2, value varchar2) is
    begin
        dbms_session.set_context (namespace=>getnamespace, attribute=>attr, value=>value);
    end;
    procedure clearctx (attr varchar2) is
    begin
        dbms_session.clear_context (namespace=>getnamespace, attribute=>attr);
    end;
end;
/
```

В сессии А:

```
select sys_context ('userenv', 'sessionid') sid from dual
/
SID
------
639285

exec gpack.setctx ('something', 'lock') 

select sys_context (gpack.getnamespace, 'something') something from dual;

SOMETHING
---------
lock
```

В сессии Б:

```
select sys_context ('userenv', 'sessionid') sid from dual
/
SID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
639321

select sys_context (gpack.getnamespace, 'something') something from dual
/
SOMETHING
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lock
```

Подробнее в [гл. документации Global Application Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/using-application-contexts-to-retrieve-user-information.html#GUID-85E9C986-4D83-4DBB-9A2E-000E737F30D6).